# Adding encoding to @GetMapping

Tags: spring, rest, kotlin, get-mapping

I want to add encoding to the response for the mapping controller. But for some reason a compilation error. Only requires an array of values

[image]

How do I add encoding to the response?

Comment: UTF-8 encoding is no longer required by Spring as the JSON should be UTF-8 by default. The [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/MediaType.html#APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8) explains it.

Comment: @kidney 
I know. I received a requirement to register explicitly. How to do it?

Comment: On a second thought - the `produces` is a String, there's no reason it should give a *compilation* error (I just checked and the mapping as you have it compiles just fine). I would look for other reasons a compilation error could be shown here. The IDE should tell you why it won't compile.

Comment: @kidney the problem is that this is not java, but kotlin. That's how it is in Kotlin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@GetMapping("/cards", produces = ["application/json;charset=UTF-8"])
```